# Add non-breaking space between required field label and asterisk in Yii

Tags: yii

I need to add a **non-breaking space** (`&nbsp;`) between the **required field label** and the `*`, to hopefully **prevent** the `*`'s from **wrapping onto a new line** (e.g. for the first field, I need the `*` to stay on the same line with at least one of the words in the label).

[image: Yii required form field wrapping asterisk]

Can anyone help me **find this in the Yii core**? I've looked for a while.

Here's another example of where this is happening:

[image: Yii required form field wrapping asterisk - 2nd example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override `$afterRequiredLabel` in `CHtml`.

The default value is currently set to `' <span class="required">*</span>'`

You will want to change it to `'&nbsp;<span class="required">*</span>'`

You could change the Yii core, but this is not advisable. Instead, you should extend `CHtml` and reference your child class moving forward.